# Travelling sales man with Quantum Computers

Tags: quantum-computing, time-complexity, quantum-information, np-complete, analysis-of-algorithms

I know that it takes billions of years to solve the travelling sales man when n = 25 (Number of cities). I am wondering how fast can a quantum computer solve the travelling sales man problem (for example, A quantum computer with 500 qubits) .I know that a quantum computer with n qubits can make 2^n in a single step and so a quantum computer with 500 qubits can make 2^500 calculations in a single step.

In classical computers, TSM has a time complexity of O(2^n). What is the time complexity if we deal with quantum computers for TSM ?

Also can a quantum traverse any loop in no time ??

Comment: "I know that a quantum computer with n qubits can make 2^n in a single step." No!

Comment: Specifically, quantum computers *do not* do anything like trying all possibilities in parallel, and selecting the possibility that works. Quantum indeterminism is much more like randomness than it is like that.

Comment: I think what quantum computers do is a lot like that.

Answer (score 5):

The set of problems that can be solved by an universal quantum computer in "polynomial time" (with at most 1/3 probability of error) is called **BQP**.

Travelling salesman problem is in complexity class called **NP**. Furthermore, it is **NP**-complete: meaning that if the Travelling Salesman Problem can be solved in any model of computation which can also simulate polynomial-time deterministic computation, then that model of computation can solve any problem in **NP**.

However, it is not yet known whether **NP** $\subseteq$ **BQP**, and the informal consensus is that this containment is in fact very unlikely. 
There is circumstantial evidence, in the sense that **NP** is not contained in **BQP** with probability 1 relative to a random oracle, and **NP $\cap$ coNP** is not contained in **BQP** with probability 1 relative to a random permutation oracle.

More generally, quantum computers do not provide any known super-polynomial advantage for solving  **NP**-complete problems. (Techniques such as Grover's Search can provide polynomial-time speedups, though.)

Most results about **BQP** are summarized at the [**BQP** article in the Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:B#bqp).

Comment: please stop making insignificant edits to old posts.

Comment: Sure. I didn't realise that I am digging out and making those questions active.